# Can't figure out Powershell Where-Object. SSAS Cube Processed State via Powershell,

Tags: powershell, ssas, cube

I've created a powershell script to list the Processed State of a number of SSAS Cubes.

I'm puzzled why the Where-Object only produces the correct results when I use -like.  I can't seem to use -eq.  Anyone got any ideas ?

I'm using the Where-Object to zero in on the production Database.

The code i'm using is this..

```
    Import-Module SQLASCmdlets -DisableNameChecking

    $SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server

    $instanceName = "SSASSVR01"
    $SSASServer.connect($instanceName)

    $ProdCubes = $SSASServer.Databases.Cubes 

    $ProdCubes | Select  Parent , State , Name `
       | Where-Object { $_.Parent -like "DWProd*" }
```

I'd expect that -eq would work, but it doesn't

I don't get any response if the last line is written as...

```
    $ProdCubes | Select  Parent , State , Name `
       | Where-Object { $_.Parent -eq "DWProd" }
```

I suspect it's whitespace, but how do you filter out the whitespace in powershell.

Comment: Turns out type conversion was needed.  The last line should be ... `$ProdCubes | Select  Parent , State , Name | Where-Object { $_.Parent.ToString() -eq "DWProd" }`